# how to extend java class with protocol having a method the same name than a clojure.core function?

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to extend a simple java class `toxi.color.ColorList` with this protocol:

```
(defprotocol countable
  (count [this]))

(extend-protocol countable
  ColorList
  (count [this]
    (.size this)))
```

when i evaluate this code i see these warning

```
Warning: protocol #'dat00.protocols/countable is overwriting function count

WARNING: count already refers to: #'clojure.core/count in namespace: dat00.protocols, being replaced by: #'dat00.protocols/count
```

But this works fine:

```
(count (ColorList.))
=> 0
```

But if I try this in same file (or namespace)

```
(count (range 5))
=> IllegalArgumentException No implementation of method: :count of protocol: #'dat00.protocols/countable found for class: clojure.lang.LazySeq  clojure.core/-cache-protocol-fn (core_deftype.clj:541)
```

So my question is:
Am i misunderstanding some detail about protocols?

Thanks!

Comment: Protocol methods cause functions of the same name to be defined in the current namespace. When you call a protocol method from some Clojure code, what you're actually calling is a generated function that looks up and dispatches to the appropriate implementation.

Comment: Thanks in advance Alex, but how would you solve this case "current namespace conflict"?

Comment: Same as you would any other namespace conflict, as described in the answers below. The fact that it happens to be a protocol method causing the conflict is of little importance.

Comment: Thanks @Alex I've published below  the 2 working solutions  for this case, with multimethods and extending protocol, both changing the function name

Answer (score 4):

You have a namespace collision.

When you define a protocol, you are defining dispatch functions in the current namespace. If you *really* want to use "count", you'll have to exclude the clojure.core version in your namespace declaration.

```
(ns so.protocols 
  (:refer-clojure :exclude [count]))
```

Now in that namespace you can define your protocol with a "count" method. If you then want the core version of count in that namespace, you can namespace prefix it `clojure.core/count`.

Users of your protocols will then want to alias your namespace. For example,

```
(ns user 
  (:require [so.protocols :as p]))
```

So that `p/count` is your protocol method and `count` is core.

Comment: thanks for explain the details to solve this namespace overlapping! But my problem (not very well explained) was also related to the expression problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3596366/what-is-the-expression-problem , then I wanted to use the same name-method-interfaz in the same case.

Answer (score 4):

There is the function `clojure.core/count` and the method `count` defined in your protocol `countable`. Like the warning says: You overwrite the alias named `count` to `clojure.core/count` by creating an interface which has a method named `count`.

The `LazySeq` object returned by `(range 5)` doesn't implement your `countable` protocol. You could still count it with `(clojure.core/count (range 5))`.

What you probably want to do is to implement the [`clojure.lang.Counted`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Counted.java) interface instead of your own.

Comment: "What you probably want to do is to implement the clojure.lang.Counted interface instead of your own." - Unfortunately OP wants to extend the protocol to an existing Java class - there's no indication that class can be modified.

Comment: Then he should create a Clojure wrapper via defrecord or using reify.

Comment: sorry @lgrapenthin i've unchecked your solution because I can not modify the Java class and,  defrecord or reify don't work either beacuse there are times that i don't create the instances :(

Comment: You have two options: 1. You create a fully featured Clojure wrapper of the ToxicLib (at least the functionality you are using directly or indirectly). It's a lot of work and should only be done if there are significant benefits. 2. This is my advice: Just use Java Interop directly which is a common idiom in Clojure - `ColorList` is not even immutable, so why would you want to make it fit into Clojure? Just use `.size` - everything else will confuse readers of your code (I'd think - It's it a Clojure coll?).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all,

I published here 2 working solution I've reached for this case, thanks to all for your comments

In all cases I have had to change the name of the function

It seems that multimethods also (I'm not yet sure about performance consequences...) can solve the expression problem here

```
(defmulti count type)

(defmethod count toxi.color.ColorList [a]
  (.size a))
(defmethod  count clojure.lang.LazySeq [a]
  (count a))
```

---

```
(defprotocol countable
  (get-count [this]))

(extend-protocol countable
  ColorList
  (get-count [this]
    (.size this))
  clojure.lang.LazySeq
    (get-count [this]
    (.count this))
  )
```

---

```
(get-count (ColorList.)) => 0
(get-count (range 5)) => 5
```

that works for me, although what I wanted to do (and with the ns colission I realized my conceptual error) was to use the "same-name-method" of different interfaces in the same ns :) ... suppose I was influenced by clojure/java interop sintaxis (the parameter defines the fn instead of the contrary) –