# How can I avoid empty (noop) method of a visitor pattern implementation?

Tags: design-patterns

I have a large collection of different objects that extend the same base class A.
To apply different algorithms to the collection, I created an IVisitor interface that has an Accept method for each child of A.

Some of the visitors that implement IVisitor actually use all children of A but many of them don't, so I end up having visitors with a bunch of empty (noop) methods that I would like to avoid.
Moreover, everytime I add a new child class of A I need to add a new Accept method to IVisitor and **all** the classes  implement it, which is a common problem of the visitor pattern.

I've tried to implement the [Selective Visitor pattern](http://www.educery.com/papers/patterns/visitors/selective.visitor.html) but I don't like to cast objects around as in my case it could be a problem.

I've also evaluated [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985960/alternative-to-the-visitor-pattern) but its answers are not really target the problem. I would like to use an interface instead of an abstract class, because in my case multiple inheritance is not allowed.

Is there a way to avoid this kind of hassle and get a cleaner code?

EDIT: Here you find an example on [Draw.io](https://www.draw.io/?lightbox=1&highlight=0000ff&edit=_blank&layers=1&nav=1&title=stackoverflow_example#R7Vttb9sqFP41kbYPrWzwS%2FKxSdu7SZ003U7bZ2KTGA0bX5ukyX79BRsc29htmjpp1KWqmnCAA5yH53B8cEdwFm%2F%2ByVAafWMhpiNghZsRvB0BYNtwIj6kZFtKfMsrBcuMhKrRTvBI%2FmAltJR0RUKcNxpyxignaVMYsCTBAW%2FIUJaxp2azBaPNUVO0xIbgMUDUlP4iIY9K6Rj4O%2FkXTJaRHtn21ILnKPi9zNgqUeONAFwUP2V1jLQutdA8QiF7qong3QjOMsZ4%2BS3ezDCVttVmK%2Fvd99RW885wwvfpAMoOa0RXaulTlOMZRXmuJsi32ij5E4kpSkRpumAJf1Q1ligHEaHhA9qylRw158IKujSNWEb%2BiPaIiipbCER1xhXmwJPaCKUzRlkmBAkrBth1epTK1DAZzkW373p1dkv0DW0aDR9QzvUEGaUozcm8mLLsGKNsSZIp45zFqpFe4H1tPjsA4VTZCmccb3rtbVcoCnZgFmOebUUT3WGigFfEgGXpabfJ7LFqEdU2mKtwQmpfLyvFO2zFFwVvD9SugfUIiDVZN0GAU%2F5pTXLCxZrFjoE34u%2FXn6XgcyVZM6GrvSuELXgBasZ%2B4xaKHcAiSpaJKFK8kN2kMYng3Y0Sc5ZKZSkKSLJ8KNrcOjvJv8okUsRE3wUtyBORMMSJxJ1xxNG82pcpIwkvbOZOxa%2Bw7My6dkeumPhMlO1dWfzK5hmfsUSsBZECTyx20BOWu2g%2F8EE3%2BAps4O2Htm73FrQ9A2yxsCDDvCT3dF922zXMArFOnPWidrgTGH9gxgOryXi7i%2FNeF%2Bedt%2B8Cv4fydxTHYv52Re1%2Br3%2Fhdw1q73l%2Bj%2FdDdgh%2B2%2FbzBL85K4J7H5jgdovflrvfLvDHA%2BwCM367EPwtBLd7sH7mBD8aw%2BHz2IILtoNiq2Psk2DrPO%2B9ZxfvfSLv7YD3dN99j2QX930gxZ3zcd%2FmE9jFfR8R25O6b%2FO56m7DcRKaEArhjUxIitKcMuk4p0KkPKvtlUXp35RVIx5rH1zqwqGRqmz5NjEeW2WBbqXzpcKd4ufTEl2myjBFnKybQ3bZSqn7LndBbzAMLNjUUM5UdarnJdt6%2FBcUlcszFBXIVUvcD8zxGYPpXMB8HZiT8wXTe08sr9pgOoeC6b6gaDgwgRklj4BH5YmRNrD0%2FlvJCxMVQpanqpVuihNWHrml%2FKo4AGWdU6uTZ%2ByVOjllnYqiK53i21J9FiOTmgDF8kSlZumr1LFAAnktbnZpaBRmIO1R5pkh0QKdl691n7cbC1nalkWZtJm%2BatPLs%2FtXepCNy9ijMnKf7q4JHmc82baw2CdcBl5V3NXMl30uhT%2BLOw4ThD3VTF9Qc6arnx0w7ZY77Y42WyFpLa5cFJ61fJhVPheo8j2KCZXu5Qumayy1drnftyXtxi0v5ppZeQA7wkdbp%2FPfdBXXfzujyH1J354sfdtKADj73s%2FAAe5n9A5rnHAvxykhyiMcKrM1o5RaCAOGCFo6o5aeJ7Hjh6CuN1AIaigaLmqB%2FTczitzndfn6kckNrfckNzh3csOuXMEJyT2eXPsT4AHPB2PbtvwmRe0DuQ5879qejG3X88bAAr4PG3rhEalvXtnM2EpmycRoRUsVhUkBW1SPA8k8T2txVkjWOszi2xQboWotHqs1NfaWyh7WdknB094UnszSoRVn6hmh7nz2ySj%2BkIXbK2egYxm2HLbVkd9zupg7QHwGux48%2B5kbSFRIMAgjYQcje946qFnC7TCEe5wTeHIgK72WnuOlDaB5q3LLcF5YOpZsCla5PIUEBVOcCduwRH5PNEkNErZIa3WRcvo3kBKMXyZl9b7T4KTsulA5DSldk5Swx1KnIaXBSv0iyKvPypYix%2FOPRkvz0uRHJHmkXjzNC%2BsVXSK0lhU4Trm0qRgkYjKDazBzjgO0ymVbHuFtxWhc8JluNa0V70vedtPUUF0wvZhawc3d0X39NzDdcZr7Au6bH3Fez3RR3L3wXm6s3X8VwLv%2FAQ%3D%3D)

Comment: Can you provide a sample code in order to clarify your question?

Comment: @MohammadaminKhayat I've linked an UML diagram

Comment: Provide a default implementation of all the Visit() methods in the interface, doing nothing (or better, throwing an exception). Which language are you using?

Comment: @JBNizet That's not feasible because the languages I use do not support multiple inheritance so the interface must be an interface, not a class

Comment: Why don't you tell us which language you're using?

Comment: C# for that matter. In my post I specified that I cannot use multiple inheritance and that should be enough ;-)

Comment: This seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 2):

You can define a new pattern ;) for your case: "Selective Generic Visitor".
You can have only one Visit method in your IVisit interface that accepts a generic parameter with constraint inherited from BaseClass.

```
interface IVisitor<T> where T:BaseClass
{
    void Visit(T element);
}
```

Then Concrete visitors can specify the generic parameter and implement the Visit method. If you can take advantage an IoC container such as [Autofac](https://autofac.org/), It serves you as a factory for generic types and easily you can get the proper Visitor instance by requesting IVisitor and pass it to Accept method calls.